# ASP.NET - server side control & javascript interaction

Tags: asp.net, javascript, visibility

on a page with textbox control, lets say this textbox is disabled on server side page load.
What would happen if a javascript tries to set visibility of the textbox to false ?

Edit:
Can the textbox be hidden by javascript even though it's disabled ?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, setting disabled on the serverside only adds the disabled attribute.

Comment: are you saying disabled textbox visibility can be set to false by javascript ?

Comment: You can't set it to false. You need to actually remove the disabled attribute via Element.removeAttribute("disabled") from the textbox on the client-side if you want to enable it. disabled="false" is still disabled. It has to do with older HTML where the attribute used to be just disabled. Because of XHTML you usually see this though disabled="true". But all of these mean it's disabled: disabled="true", disabled="false", disabled="bob", disabled="WTF"

Comment: @Wisdom - You can use CSS to hide it regardless of whether or not it's disabled. Either visible: hidden or display: none . Here's an explanation of the difference, http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13638 . So on IE6+ and other modern browsers you can usually just do this: someElement.style.display="none" or someElement.style.display="hidden" or you can use a framework like jQuery to do this, e.g. $("#someElementId").css("display", "none");

Answer (score 0):

`controlID.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");`
This disables the control...

`controlID.Attributes.Remove("disabled");`
This enables the control.